# How to get size of div based on class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following HTML file that currently has nothing in it except some div class objects that are specified by CSS styles.  If I open this web page and inspect the elements in Chrome they are the sizes that I want them to be.  What I am wondering is if I can access those sizes via javascript.

HTML File:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">

<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

    <title>TEST</title>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <style type="text/css">

        .camp_cont {
            float: left;
            width: 45%;
            height: 50%;
            position: relative;
        }

        .camp_cont_select {
            float: left;
            width: 45%;
            height: 50%;
            position: relative;
            fill: #800;
        }

        .sub_camp_cont {
            float: left;
            width: 15%;
            height: 50%;
            position: relative;
            margin: 10px 25px;
            fill: #800;
        }

    </style>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="camp_cont", id="cpa_perf"></div>
    <div class="camp_cont", id="ctr_perf"></div>
    <div class="sub_camp_cont", id="as_perf"></div>
    <div class="sub_camp_cont", id="f_perf"></div>
    <div class="sub_camp_cont", id="rh_perf"></div>
    <div class="sub_camp_cont", id="rm_perf"></div>
    <div class="sub_camp_cont", id="rl_perf"></div>
    <div class="sub_camp_cont", id="ul_perf"></div>
    <div class="sub_camp_cont", id="rt_perf"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

I am wondering if I can do something like the following:

```
x = $("#cpa_perf").width()
```

Again, when I inspect cpa_perf in Chrome it says its width is 515px.  That's what I'm trying to get at

Comment: Well, did you try it? and `<div class="camp_cont", id="cpa_perf">` should be `<div class="camp_cont" id="cpa_perf">` kill the commas for all of them. Here it works http://jsfiddle.net/wy7t3kvc/ Don't forget to include jquery in your actual page. Currently it looks like you don't have jquery on your markup... unless d3 includes it

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/width/

Comment: Yes I tried it, that's what I'm so confused.  When I am looking at the objects in Chrome I can clearly see the pixel size, but I can't find a way to access it in the console.  For example `$("#cpa_perf").width()` returns an undefined function.  The closest I can get to the CSS style is `$("#cpa_perf").className`, but that doesn't give me access to the parameters

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/9abcf9d3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[jQuery Width](http://api.jquery.com/width) works just fine for this:

```
x = $("#cpa_perf").width();
alert(x);
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9abcf9d3/

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery pretty easily to modify attributes of elements..

```
$('.classname').css(property, value);
```

Comment: But how do I read the property value?  trying `.css("width")` did not work

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain if you are trying to use jQuery or pure javascript.

You're original attempt to get the width of the element should work as long as you're using a jQuery library.

Otherwise, if you just want the width of the element with pure javascript, you can use something like this:

```
var x = document.getElementById('cpa_perf').offsetWidth;
```

If you are including a jQuery library then the following should work:

```
var x = $("#cpa_perf").width()
```

Additional Note: Make sure that the script isn't called before the DOM element is written to the page as well. For example:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    var x = $("#cpa_perf").width();
    console.log(x);
}) ;
```